# search for values after specific string-multiple columns

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have this file (copied from vim):

```
name: some name^M
^M
count: 1^M
^M
region: some_region
name: some name^M
^M
count: 2^M
^M
region: some_region^M
^M
name: some name^M
^M
count: 1^M
^M
region: some_region^M
^M

Testing Powershell scripts execustions from Rundeck server against Windows server
```

How to get only values after name,count and region

desired output:

```
some name 1 some region
some name 2 some region
some name 1 some region
```

with   `grep -E 'name|count|region' output.txt | sed 's/^.*: //'`

i got

```
some name
1
some_region
some name
2
some_region
some name
1
some_region
```

How to generate multiple columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved mentioned output in 2 steps

In first step1 i am searched for pattern and saved in a file Output.txt

In second step2 i have used for loop and print the content as per requirement

step1

```
egrep -i "name|count|region" l.txt | awk -F ":" '{print $NF}' | sed "s/\^M//g" >> Ouput.txt
```

step2

```
for ((i=1;i<=9;i=i+3)); do sed -n ''$i',+2p' Output.txt |sed "N;s/\n/ /g" |sed "N;s/\n/ /g"; done
```

output

```
 some name  1  some_region
 some name  2  some_region
 some name  1  some_region
```

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^(name|count|region):/{
         sep = (/^region/? ORS : OFS);
         gsub(/^[^:]+:[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$/, "");
         printf "%s%s", $0, sep 
     }' file.txt
```

The output:

```
some name 1 some_region
some name 2 some_region
some name 1 some_region
```

Comment: great, i'm in debt to you Roman !

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer using awk:

```
awk '/name: /{name=substr($0,7)} /count: /{cnt=substr($0,8)} /region:/{print name" "cnt" "substr($0,9)}' input
```

Comment: doesn't work, only get `some region`(x3) as result